# Change shade color for watched tags on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, design, tag-watching

Can I change the *yellow shade color* for the highlighted watched tags on Stack Overflow?

May be I am a color-blind or my LCD monitor is not very good, but I can barely see the highlighted watched tags in the list of questions.

I understand that there may be a userscript, but can't we have an inbuilt option? I am looking to just **make a shade little more prominent**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt they will add an option for this. To fix it yourself, you can use an extension such as Stylish to change the color to whatever you want. The current CSS for it is:

```css
.tagged-interesting {
    background-color: #fffbec;
}
```

You can add a similar rule with a different color.

Comment: I ended up installing `Stylish` and used your script. This works great.

Comment: Is Stylish safe to use again? Cf. https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/07/05/browsers_pull_stylish_but_invasive_browser_extension/

Comment: @Glorfindel Good question. I assumed it is because it was forcibly removed from chrome and firefox, and I assumed that it wouldn't have been allowed back unless they fixed it. It may still be safer to use a different extension anyways, though.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I've asked [the experts](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/199218/71850) to be sure.

Answer (score 4):

We'll be revisiting how we indicate questions with watched tags next year. As we've been releasing the updated themes over the last six months, this concern was repeated on several sites. The pale yellow is difficult to see for some users, and particularly on some sites where the question background isn't white, like the cream used on English Language & Usage:

[image: Screenshot of English Language & Usage question list with two unfollowed tags and one followed - I can't tell the difference!]

I've got great color vision and I can barely tell which is which.

What this really tells us is what experts in accessibility already know:

#### Color isn't the best way to indicate... anything.

At least, not on its own. So, we're going to be reworking how we indicate watched tags when we look at accessibility early next year. I'm not sure what it's going to look like at this point but it will be either moving away from color entirely or adding something so that it's not color alone.

Comment: I agree. Colors can useful, but it can also be distracting. I can tell from my experience. I changed the color to little darker shade of yellow as described above. And an interesting thing happened. I could see all my watched tags show up nice and clear. But my mind also started to `ignore` other questions, some of which might be of my interest. I had to make an `extra` effort to read through those `other questions`. Hope it makes sense.